# can I connect my d750 to the mains?

Tags: nikon, usb, power-supply, nikon-d750

I am using my Nikon D750 to record behavioural trials in the lab. It is a real pain to have to worry about battery level and having charged spares and a charger on hand in addition to all the rest of the organisational issues associated with the experiments.

Additionally, it is a really big problem if the camera shuts down in the middle of the recording.

It would be really great if I could hook it up to the mains via a USB charger or similar, I have, however, not found any microUSB port on it. Does it maybe have its own proprietary charger port which I just don't recognise? Can I hook it up via the battery pack contacts? Or via the accessory terminal?

Comment: @dpollitt the last paragraph is focused on USB. People look for that because they are used to it from other devices while the true question underneath is always to power the camera by any means. (see accepted answer from the question) I don't think we need to answer this question for every specific camera model and the answers that the question I linked to received make it a suitable canonical question.

Comment: @null - Agree we do not need a question for each model. Either duplicate is fine and will get the correct information across. We disagree that the focus is USB, that is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nikon EH-5b power adapter will do this. 
For your camera model you would also need the EP-5B battery adpter via which to connect the EH-5b.

Try typing in "nikon d750 power adapter europe" to Google. It will be the first result.